# Index out of range error when clicking foreign key link in Dynamic Data DetailsView

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

Using ASP.NET, I created dynamic data folder using custom pages. The table in the DB that this folder refers to has 3 FK's, which appear as hyperlinks when viewed on screen inside the table (see below)

[image: screenshot of DetailsView control]

Take the first record for an example, When I click on 'thur 21st march' or '100' it will bring me to the corresponding page i.e the particular diary page or invoice page.

However problem being when I click on 'over there' to load the subcontractor page the application crashes at:

```
void DetailsView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rowCount = DetailsView1.Rows.Count;

    SetDelete(DetailsView1.Rows[rowCount - 1]);
}
```

The error is:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index

Comment: Your `DetailsView` has zero rows when you set rowCount there, so your (rowCount - 1) index is negative.  That's what's causing the error.

Comment: I don't understand how does it have zero rows if it is displaying a sub contractor

Comment: I wonder if it's an issue with the order of the DataBinding?  Call `DetailsView1.DataBind();` at the beginning of that _PreRender method to see if that's the issue.